# macports confusion

Tags: macos, macports

hey i am new to the macports thing as i recently switched to the mac. as i was thinking of developing some applications in my mac i wanted all the usual gnu and opensource tools i need. but i had a small confusion. i was installing git with macports and i noticied it installed a lot of packages like Perl that i already have in my machne. so i was thinking won't there be any conflicts and how does one know which version is used. the macports one or the apple one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MacPorts installs all of its ports into `/opt/local` (or whatever prefix you configured it with, but it's `/opt/local` by default). It installs its own copies of Perl, Python, etc., so that the MacPorts install is standardized, and to avoid conflicts (Apple-supplied versions of some programs like Perl and Python, and some libraries, often lag far behind the latest versions of those tools).

When you install MacPorts, it automatically prepends `/opt/local/bin` to your `$PATH` variable (you can change this by editing your shell configuration file), so if you call `perl`, etc., you'll get the MacPorts version. However, the Apple-supplied versions will still be intact and unchanged, and other programs that rely on those versions will not be affected, either.

Comment: One caution though: if you use /opt/local/bin first in your $PATH so that the MacPorts version has precedence, be aware that there *may* be a difference between a MacPorts version and the Apple-supplied one.  The one concrete and potentially critical example I've been burned by in the past is `rsync` which is pulled in as a dependency by the MacPorts `git-core` package. Unfortunately, the MacPorts rsync -aE option differs from the Apple rsync -aE: extended attributes and resource forks are silently ignored which may result in a nasty surprise later when you try to use the copied files.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any conflicts, since MacPorts installs all of its programs under a completely separate directory hierarchy in `/opt/local/`.

If you have multiple versions of software installed (e.g. the default OS X Perl and MacPorts' Perl), then it depends on the order of directories in your `$PATH` environment variable.  MacPorts typically sets itself up with its `bin` directories earlier in your path, so saying `perl` at the command line will invoke the MacPorts Perl, not the OS X Perl.

Answer (score 1):

MacPorts installs its own dependencies in the `/opt/local` tree (you can change this default when you build MacPorts) because its packagers then have a known quantity to test against. In some cases there is a system package for a given dependency that will let you use the system-installed version, but that's actually pretty rare. System vs. MacPort versions are chosen according to whichever comes first on the `PATH` (for executables) or the linker path(s) for dynamic libraries. Use your standard development tools' options to select the appropriate libraries to link against and you should be fine.